# Test failing for unexpected Collections.sort behavior

Tags: java, sorting, junit, collections

**Please note:** I mention JUnit here and provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) code example using it but this is a Java collections question at heart and can be answered by anyone with Java experience regardless of their experience with JUnit.

---

Java 8 here and I am trying to sort a list of strings but am getting some unexpected behaviors out of `Collections.sort(myList)` and am wondering what is happening.

Here is my full unit test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SorterTest {

    @Test
    public void should_sort_correctly_including_capitalization_rules() {

        // given
        String[] actualNames = new String[] {
            "DCME",
            "CCME",
            "ACME",
            "BCME",
            "AGME",
            "AACME",
            "aCME",
            "Acme",
            "AaCME",
            "aACME",
        };
        List<String> actual = Arrays.asList(actualNames);

        // the order I would *expect* them to sort into...
        String[] expectedNames = new String[] {
                "aACME",
                "aCME",
                "AaCME",
                "AACME",
                "Acme",
                "ACME",
                "AGME",
                "BCME",
                "CCME",
                "DCME"
        };
        List<String> expected = Arrays.asList(expectedNames);

        // when
        Collections.sort(actual);

        // then
        assertTrue(actual.equals(expected));

    }

}
```

The JUnit `assertTrue` here fails at runtime because the `actual` list is sorted into:

```
0 = "AACME"
1 = "ACME"
2 = "AGME"
3 = "AaCME"
4 = "Acme"
5 = "BCME"
6 = "CCME"
7 = "DCME"
8 = "aACME"
9 = "aCME"
```

Thats ^^^ debugger output, and the numbers represent the list index of each element.

So for some reason `Collections.sort` is saying that the string "BCME" is lexiconographically "lower" (will appear earlier in a sorted list) than "aCME", which is just plain nuts to me. :-)

I should mention that I will only be dealing with ASCII characters in UTF-8 here, but my application will perform pre-validation that assures us all characters in each string/name will be in the range of `[a-z][A-Z]`.

Either way, the sorting rules I'm looking for my Java code to use are this:

- when I say "*lower*", I mean "*will appear earlier in a sorted list*" and when I say "higher" I mean "*will appear later in a sorted list*"

  - hence I would say "3 is lower than 43", because in a sorted list of ints, 3 will appear earlier in that list than 43 would, etc.
- lower-case letters are **lower** than uppercase; so "a" should appear before "A"

  - hence the order of all letters is `aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ`
- shorter words come before longer words, provided that they are an identical (casing included) subsets of the longer word

  - "but" is lower than (comes before) "butterfly"
  - "butterfly" is lower than "But" (b < B)
  - "butterfly" is lower than "bUt" (b and b are the same, but u < U)

Given these sorting rules, the list from my unit test should sort into:

```
Sort Order   Reason why it comes after the last one in the list
================================================================
aACME        
aCME         1st letter is 'a' but 2nd letter is 'C' and A < C
AaCME        1st letter is 'A' and a < A
AACME        1st letter is 'A' and 2nd letter is 'A' and a < A
Acme         1st letter is 'A' but 2nd letter is 'c' and A < c
ACME         1st letter is 'A' but 2nd letter is 'C' and c < C
AGME         1st letter is 'A' but 2nd letter is 'G' and C < G
BCME         1st letter is 'B' and aA < bB
CCME         1st letter is 'C' and bB < cC
DCME         1st letter is 'D' and cC < dD
```

**How can I change the code above so that the unit test passes and the list is sorted the way I need?**

Comment: why would `aCME` come before `AaCME`? you say yourself that `aAbBcC...` is the order, so this is sort of confusing

Comment: The first letter in `aCME` is `a`. The first letter in `AaCME` is `A`. And `a` is lower than `A`.

Comment: Where do the digits fall in relation to alpha?

Comment: Please read my question @JimGarrison you will see that I mentioned pre-validation that ensures all characters are in the range `[a-z][A-Z]`.

Comment: Then why bother explaining that `3` comes before `4`?

Comment: To provide an example of what "lower" means since, in its absence, I can see all sorts of SO denizens complaining about the question, citing I didn't specify what is implied by "lower".

Comment: So is it fair to say that what you want to accomplish is to sort overall case-insensitive, but for each upper/lowercase pair you want the lowercase first?  I.e. All `a`s (regardless of case) come before `b`, `c` (again regardless of case) but when comparing `a` and `A` the lower-case letter comes first?

Comment: You have very well explained what you *wish*, but not why you *expected* the built-in behavior to match you wishes and even call it “plain nuts”. The term “lexicographically” is very well defined. When you try `System.out.println('B' < 'a');`, it will print `true`. Java uses Unicode whose codepoints for `'B'` and `a` can be traced back to ASCII which was defined in the sixties of the last century and influenced by even older technical reasons. Computers follow rules, not wishful thinking.

Comment: Then the rules are nuts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java has [class `RuleBasedCollator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html) which allows to customize sorting/ordering of characters.

In this case, lower case letters should come before the upper case letters, so the rules may look as follows:

```java
static RuleBasedCollator lowerFirst() {
    try {
        return new RuleBasedCollator(
            "< a < A < b < B < c < C < d < D < e < E < f < F < g < G < h < H < i < I < j < J < "
            + "k < K < l < L < m < M < n < N < o < O < p < P < q < Q < r < R < s < S < t < T < "
            + "u < U < w < W < x < X < y < Y < z < Z"
        );
    } catch (ParseException parsex) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to create lowerFirst collator", parsex);
    }
}
```

Test:

```java
String[] names = new String[] {
    "DCME",  "CCME", "ACME", "BCME",  "AGME",
    "AACME", "aCME", "Acme", "AaCME", "aACME",
};

String[] expected = new String[] {
    "aACME", "aCME", "AaCME", "AACME", "Acme",
    "ACME", "AGME", "BCME", "CCME", "DCME"
};
        
Arrays.sort(names, lowerFirst());

System.out.println("sorted:   " + Arrays.toString(names));
System.out.println("expected: " + Arrays.toString(expected));
```

Output

```
sorted:   [aACME, aCME, AaCME, AACME, Acme, ACME, AGME, BCME, CCME, DCME]
expected: [aACME, aCME, AaCME, AACME, Acme, ACME, AGME, BCME, CCME, DCME]
```

Comment: this is great, first time I hear about such a class.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you only have letters, you can define a comparator something like:

```
Comparator<String> comparator = (a, b) -> {
    // Compare the characters pairwise.
    for (int i = 0, m = Math.min(a.length(), b.length()); i < m; ++i) {
      char aa = a.charAt(i);
      char bb = b.charAt(i);
      // If one is lowercase but the other isn't, say that the lowercase comes first.
      if (Character.isLowerCase(aa) != Character.isLowerCase(bb)) {
        return Character.isLowerCase(aa) ? -1 : 1;
      }

      // If the characters are the same case but aren't the same, say the lexicographically first one is first.
      if (aa != bb) {
        return aa < bb ? -1 : 1;
      }
    }
    // If the pair-wise comparison doesn't find a difference, say the shortest one is first; or they are equal if the same length.
    return Integer.compare(a.length(), b.length());
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Andy Turner (+1) how would I wire this comparator up to my list so I can use it for sorting?

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup you can't "wire it" into the list: you have to pass it to sort: `list.sort(comparator)`.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this comparator sorts `Acme` as coming _before_ `AACME`, which doesn't hold up to what I'm looking for, since the 2nd letter in `Acme` is `c` and the 2nd letter in `AACME` is `A` and `A < c`.

Answer (score 0):

Write a comparator to sort things the way you want. We're not going to write it for you, but it should be simple to have the comparator map/translate the strings into corresponding sort keys...

For example, assuming only `[A-Za-z]` map

```
a->0x00
A->0x01 
b->0x02
B->0x03
```

etc.

Remember that the comparator will visit elements more than once, so if the data volume is sufficiently high (say, >10<sup>6</sup> strings) and performance is an issue, you might have to cache the sort keys.

Comment: "_We're not going to write it for you_" LOL